# CruiseControl.NET build project with VSS

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to get a build going for a client that pulls from VSS 2005 (yes, I have no choice). I am pretty sure I have all my configuration correct, but I keep getting this error:

> Source control operation failed: $/Utilities/Orbital Gateway/Solution Architecture/Release Construction/Payment Subsystem/Services/PaymentService is not an existing filename or project

I have copied the project path directly from SourceSafe so I know it is correct.

Here is my config:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vss" autoGetSource="true">
  <executable>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\ss.exe"</executable>
  <project>"$/Utilities/Solution Architecture/Release Construction/Payment Subsystem/Services/PaymentService"</project>
  <username>XXXXXX</username>
  <password>XXXXXXX</password>
  <ssdir>\\server\VSS_Data\<ssdir>
  <workingDirectory>C:\Builds\PaymentService\Dev</workingDirectory>
  <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Does the executable mean the ss.exe on the build server, or the server the code is actually housed. I have it pointed to the build server.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted.  And with no comment why...  +1 to make up for that.

Answer (score 1):

The ss.exe is the SourceSafe executable on the build server since it will do a checkout before building the sources. The docs state that you can omit this if VSS is running on the same machine as the build server.

> The location of SS.EXE. If VSS is installed on the integration server, the location of VSS will be read from the registry and this element may be omitted.

Your config seems correct though.

Docs: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Visual+Source+Safe+Source+Control+Block

Answer (score 0):

The question I have is why is it not finding the project at \server\vss_data?

Something else to note is that in the error message, it has "Orbital Gateway" between "Utilities" and "Solution Architecture", but in your example script, that part of the path is missing.